# unifying touch and click events

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, touch, multi-touch

I'd assume this question has been asked to death, but I'm not finding anything good.
What I'd like is a unified set of events that span devices. I know the mapping isn't always 1 to 1, but just something that covers the basics like:

- ignores/disables hover events/styles on a touch device
- maps a touchstart to a mousedown
- similarly, touchend to mouseup
- tap to click
- etc...
- maybe even touch, hold 1s, touchmove to dragstart...

I haven't thought through all the specifics. And of course device specific events like hover on a desktop, or swipe on a tablet, can't be translated and should just be ignored if not supported.

Anybody know of a library that will do this. Preferably an invisible jQuery patch.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) does exactly this, amongst many other things.

See their documentation on [virtual mouse events](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/api/events.html), which:

> ... provide a set of "virtual" mouse events that attempt to abstract away mouse and touch events

Comment: Thanks! I thought jQuery Mobile was a complete package with a ton of built in behaviors that I don't want. I'll take a look and see if I can just rip out their event handling.