# Creating a bind that supports touch and click

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, touch, desktop

I'm looking for a bind that binds "touchstart" for touch devices and "click" for desktop devices.

Binding "click" on some touch devices gives a 500ms delay before the click is handled.

Separating touch devices from desktop with "typeof window.ontouchstart" does not work anymore as major browsers now support touch ([jQuery TouchClick](https://github.com/tuxracer/jquery-touchclick)), but a click with a mouse does not emulate a touch event.

[jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/api/events.html) has this feature, [as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11752506/unifying-touch-and-click-events?rq=1), but I'm looking for a stripped down jQuery plugin for this feature without using the jQuery Mobile framework.

Comment: Why not bind both, and set a flag inside the touch listener which the click listener can check for and ignore if true?

Answer (score 1):

What about binding both, then when a touch is triggered, ignore the subsequent click event?

```
var ignoreClick = false;

function touchOrClick(e){
    if (e.type == 'click'){
        if (ignoreClick){
            ignoreClick = false;
            return;
        }
    } else {
        ignoreClick = true;
    }
    // do stuff
}

node.addEventListener('ontouchstart', touchOrClick, false);
node.addEventListener('onclick', touchOrClick, false);
```

Comment: Thank for the reply. This works, but I'm also looking for a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you upgrade to the latest version of jquery-touchclick it now supports both.